# AWS Cognito - Adding custom attributes while using federated sign in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

While signing in with a federated identity provider, is there a way we can add custom attributes with the federatedSignIn call, so that we can map them inside Cognito user pool's custom attribute. I have the following scenario:

Website: https://www.example.com/invite/:username -> google/facebook sign in(federatedSignIn call goes here) -> back to my app(cognito returns the authenticated user info).

I want to keep track of the username present in the invite link and set that as a custom attribute for the user in the user pool.

Is this possible with federated sign-ins?

Thanks

Comment: are u using federate login in Cognito User Pool or Identity?

Comment: Yes, I am using external federated identity providers like Google/Facebook for signing in, apart from a normal sign-in process.

Comment: Im asking you are using Userpool or Identity? Which one?

Comment: I am using userpool

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Were you able to find a way to resolve this? I need the exact same funtionality.

Comment: Had the same problem. Seems like Cognito does not support attributes for federated sign in. What I did was saving the referer ID in the localstorage and once the dashboard is opened retrieved it and called an endpoint to update the database (or you can retrieve the user from Cognito and at that point probably attach an attribute).